# Issues with getting a counter to work in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a button in Google sheets which, when pressed, imports a sheet from a separate spreadsheet into the current one and gives it a name of 'Miscellaneous' followed by the number 1 through to infinity.

For example, the first time the button is pressed it will import a sheet and call it 'Miscellaneous 1' and the second time I press the button it will import a second sheet called 'Miscellaneous 2', so on...

I have the import working and now I'm trying to use a counter to increment the number after 'Miscellaneous'. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The error is occurring on line 22

> template.copyTo(currentSpreadsheet).setName(newName);

```
var n = 0;

function countUp() {
    n += 1;
}

function copyFromTemplate(){
  var templateSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1iXnLkMaPh73lcnkXP1yRV53H824y24FUa1a297OmAKk');
  var template = templateSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; //Assuming it is the first sheet

  //The default name will be "Copy of [original name]". We can use this to change it

    countUp();

  var newName = ("Miscellaneous " + n);




  var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  template.copyTo(currentSpreadsheet).setName(newName);


}
```

Comment: Line 22 here is blank.

Comment: Apologies my line 22 is template.copyTo(currentSpreadsheet).setName(newName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you want to increase counter and copy sheet by clicking a button for launching function of `copyFromTemplate()`. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- About the error, I think that your script works. So please confirm the source file ID of `1iXnLkMaPh73lcnkXP1yRV53H824y24FUa1a297OmAKk`, and whether your script is a bound script of destination Spreadsheet, again.
- In your script, since the counter `n` is not saved, when you launch `copyFromTemplate()` by a button, the counter is always 1.

The modified script which reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function countUp() {
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var n = prop.getProperty("n");
  n = n ? parseInt(n, 10) + 1 : 1;
  prop.setProperty("n", n);
  return n;
}

function copyFromTemplate(){
  var templateSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1iXnLkMaPh73lcnkXP1yRV53H824y24FUa1a297OmAKk');
  var template = templateSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var newName = ("Miscellaneous " + countUp());
  var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  template.copyTo(currentSpreadsheet).setName(newName);
}
```

#### Note :

- I used [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) for increasing counter.

  - When `countUp()` is run, `n` is increased by 1.
  - You can see the current counter at

    - On script editor
    - File -> Project properties -> Script properties
- When you run `copyFromTemplate()`, the counter `n` is increased and `template` is copied to current active spreadsheet as filename of `Miscellaneous "n"`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @whowantsmalk Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.